# Cómo hacer que un menú ocupe todo el ancho de la página con CSS

Tags: html, css

Hice un menu horizontal abajo de un `div` pero tengo un ligero problema:

El menú no ocupa todo el ancho de la página, deja un espacio a los lados.

```css
#inicio
{
 background-color:#020213;
 color:white;
 min-width :100%;
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:auto;
 left:0; right:0; top:0;
}
#data
{
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom:-1000px;
 padding-bottom:1000px;
}
#parteizquierda
{
 width:200px;
 height:100%;
 background-color:white;
 margin-bottom:-1000px;
 float:left;
 padding-bottom:1000px;
}
#derecha
{
 width:200px;
 height:100%;
 background-color:white;
 margin-bottom:-1000px;
 float:right;
 padding-bottom:1000px;
}
#menu{
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul li 
{
 float: left;
 list-style:none;
}
ul li a
{
 padding:.3em;
 float:left;
 padding-right:7em;
 display:block;
 border-right:2px solid;
 border-top: 1px solid #7C7C7C;
 border-bottom:1px solid #7C7C7C;
 border-left:1 px solid ;
 background-color:red;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:.1em;
 margin-left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="hola.css"/>
  <title> Cine </title>
 </head >
 <body>
  <div id="inicio">
   <h1/>
   <p>hola</p>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/> 
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <ul id="menu">
   <h2/>
   <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div  id="data"></div>
  <div id="parteizquierda"></div>
  <div id="derecha"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: deberias no usar <br> en lo posible, casi todo deberia ser puros `<div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo no usar la etiqueta `<br />`, o evitar su uso en lo posible, particularmente la uso en contados casos, es posible lograr lo mismo ajustando el estilo CSS de los elementos.

En la primera validación que hice a tu código veo que se está generando un espacio debido a que la etiqueta body aplica un margin por defecto.

Este MARGIN no afecta al `div#inicio` debido a que tiene posición absoluta y esta es referenciada por el ancestro con posición relativa más cercano, para el caso tuyo no existe por lo que se toma la ventana como posición relativa.

En resumen el espacio se debe al margin del body.

Comment: Creo que convendría incluir el fragmento de código, mostrando cómo eliminar ese margen en CSS

Comment: gracias entonces que me recoiendas hacer

Comment: Solo es necesario agregar un estilo así:

`body{margin:0;}`

Incluso si lo modificas en el **iframe** a través de la consola de **Chrome** o **Firefox**, puedes ver el efecto inmediato.

Comment: Hola Mariano, tienes razón acabo de agregar una respuesta con un código de ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al código indicado, debería quedar algo así:
Pero si amplias la información de lo que requieres se puede ampliar el ejemplo.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font:400 12px/12px sans-serif;
}

/*CONTENEDOR DEL TÍTULO*/
#content div.inicio{
  background-color:#F0F0F0;
  
  }

/*CONFIGURACIÓN DEL TÍTULO*/
#content div.inicio h1{
  font:300 1.3em/2em sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding:.5em;
}

#content ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#E6DEFF;
  }

#content ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#CCC;
  margin:0;
}
#content ul li:hover{
  background-color:#FFF;
  }

/*CONFIGURACIÓN DE LOS PANELES DE CONTENIDO*/
#content div.data{
  display:block;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:        flex;
  margin-top:2em;
}

/*CONFIGURACIÓN GENERAL DE LOS DOS PANELES*/
#content div.data > div{
  display:inline-block;
  flex:1;
  padding:20px;
}

#content div.data div.izquierda{
  background-color:#DDEAFD;
}

#content div.data div.derecha{
  background-color:#EBF7C4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Cine </title>
  </head >
  <body>
    <div id='content'>
      <div class="inicio">
        <h1>Título</h1>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Opción 1</a>
        </li><li>
          <a href="#">Opción 2</a>
        </li><li>
          <a href="#">Opción 3</a>
        </li><li>
          <a href="#">Opción 4</a>
        </li><li>
          <a href="#">Opción 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  
      <div class="data">
        <div class="izquierda">
         Contenido Parte Izquierda 
        </div>

        <div class="derecha">
         Contenido Parte Derecha
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```